# Cannot find type 'Content' in Scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm working on an XCode project and can't figure out how to get rid of this error. I have imported the SwiftUI library which 'Content' is from but XCode doesn't seem to realize that. Any suggestions?

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .blur(radius: spotify.isAuthorized ? 0 : 3)
        .overlay(
            ZStack {
                if !spotify.isAuthorized || Self.debugAlwaysShowing {
                    Color.black.opacity(0.25)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    if self.finishedViewLoadDelay || Self.debugAlwaysShowing {
                        loginView
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        .onAppear {
            // After the app first launches, add a short delay before
            // showing this view so that the animation can be seen.
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                withAnimation(LoginViewController.animation) {
                    self.finishedViewLoadDelay = true
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the enclosing type (eg the struct signature)?

Comment: I've answered in a generic way, but can make it more precise to your situation if you give more detail

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Content` without telling the compiler enough detail about it. In `ViewModifier` and `AnimatableModifier`, `Content` is already defined for you as an `associatedType` by the SwiftUI library.

If you are inside a `View` or a custom struct type of your own making, `Content` won't be defined, but you can let the compiler know it's a `View` by doing something like this:

```
struct MyStruct<Content> where Content : View {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.background(Color.black)
    }
}
```

If it's a ViewModifier, like I described, the compiler already knows the constraint and you'll see no error:

```
struct ExampleStruct : ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.background(Color.black)
    }
}

struct ExampleStruct2 : AnimatableModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.background(Color.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is exact deference between ViewModifier and AnimatableModifier? as I use just ViewModifier it does do same like AnimatableModifier, so why we should use AnimatableModifier? Also can you show use case of **MyStruct**? how can I use that struct?

Comment: @swiftPunk ViewModifier modifies a regular view. AnimatableModifier is geared towards providing animated modifications to a view that change over time. Regarding an example of `MyStruct`, I don't think that's well-suited to answering in the comments on another question